# TPH inheritance issue in efcore

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.2

I have these classes:

```
public class Sog
{
    public Int32 Id { get; set; } = 0;
    public Boolean FlagCrm { get; set; } = false;
    public Boolean FlagWms { get; set; } = false;
}
public class SogCrm : Sog
{
    //Properties of SogCrm
}
public class SogWms : Sog
{
    //Properties of SogWms
}
```

Entity Framework automatically creates column in database called "Discriminator": this means that if I create a new SogCrm (for example, with Id=3), this object will be SogCrm forever. So, if I want to get SogWms instead SogCrm, i can't read the object with Id=3 because it is marked as SogCrm.

So I added 2 boolean columns instead of Discriminator: FlagCrm and FlagWms; if a object has FlagCrm=true, it can be retrieved as SogCrm, and eventually if the same object has FlagWms=true it can be retrieved as SogWms too.
This is more flexible than a single Discriminator column, but the following code doesn't work:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Sog>()
            .HasDiscriminator(x => new { crm = x.FlagCrm, wms = x.FlagWms })
            .HasValue<Sog>(new { crm = false, wms = false })
            .HasValue<SogCrm>(new { crm = true, wms = false })
            .HasValue<SogWms>(new { crm = false, wms = true });
    }
```

any ideas?

Comment: Idea? Yes, remove the subtypes from your code. If they can be both, it's not their identity ("is a") so there's no basis for inheritance. If they can have different behaviour depending on the flag values, use one of the runtime behavioral OO patterns, for example *strategy*.